# Find all files that need updating

Tags: bash, for-loop

I use the script below to convert all pdf files in a directory to png files, and I want to run it only over the files that have yet to be converted.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Convert pdf to png
for f in *.pdf
do
    echo "Converting $f"
    gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=png256 -r480 -q -sOutputFile="png/$f.png" "$f"
done
rename -f 's/\.pdf\.png/\.png/' png/*.pdf.png
```

How do I modify the loop so that it is restricted to files where the corresponding png file either does not exist or is older than the pdf file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple modification to your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Convert pdf to png
for f in *.pdf
do
    png="png/${f%pdf}png"
    if [ -e "$png" -a "$f" -nt "$png" ]; then
        continue
    fi

    echo "Converting $f"
    gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=png256 -r480 -q -sOutputFile="$png" "$f"
done
```

Firstly, we create a `$png` variable using in place editing. Basically the `%pdf` tells bash to remove the last occurrence of `pdf`, which is the extension. Then we can place this into a string that prefixes it with `png/` and adds the png extension. This saves you the last rename command.

Now we have an `if` statement that `continue`s the loop if a certain condition is met. Continue means go to the next iteration of the loop, without executing anything else for this iteration. The condition is "$png" exists (`-e "$png"`) and (`-a`) "$f" is newer than "$png" (`"$f" -nt "$png"`).

But I would suggest writing a Makefile:

```
PDFS := $(wildcard *.pdf)
PNGS := $(addprefix png/,$(PDFS:.pdf=.png))
all: $(PNGS)
png/%.png: %.pdf
    gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=png256 -r480 -q -sOutputFile="$@" "$<"
```

And run it with `make` any time you want to generate newer PNGs.

Comment: The script is still grabbing every file. I tried your Makefile and I think there is a comma missing in the second line. But even with that comma, it thinks there is nothing to do even after I create new or revised pdfs.

Comment: Added missing comma, and fixed wildcard expansion. Hope this does it =)

Comment: OK. I'm now getting the error: 
make: *** No rule to make target `png/telec.png', needed by `all'.  Stop.
So it is detecting that a new png is required, but it doesn't seem to know how to make it.

Comment: Also note of the tab pitfall in make: after the `png/%.png: %.pdf` line, the line containing the command to run **must** start with a tab character (IIRC).